# Windows 10 EV code signing no longer works on electron app

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, code-signing-certificate, electron-forge, safenet

I have an electron app.  Pretty basic app.  It doesn't use ffmpeg for anything it does play an mp3 chime from time to time.  I build my app with electron-forge using squirrel format.  I then sign it using the SafeNet Authentication app.  It's always worked flawlessly.

It's been a couple months since I last released a version.  Only thing that has changed is some html ui updates within my electron app and of course lots of Windows 10 updates.

My app builds fine using electron-forge, it installs and runs without issue.  I then sign it like usual from the command line and SafeNet confirms it was signed.  Right clicking on the file shows it has been signed by my organization.  However, once I execute the signed app I get this error: "The code execution cannot proceed because ffmpeg.dll was not found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Building/Signing on a different windows 10 machine.
- Uninstall/Reinstall SafeNet.
- Running signed .exe on a different Windows 10 instance
- Building/Signing with a cmd session ran as administrator

I am at a loss, why is it screaming about ffmpeg.dll which my app doesn't depend on?  Why only after the .exe has been signed do I get this error?

OS: Windows 10
Electron v7.3.2
Electron-Forge/cli v6.0.0-beta.47
SafeNet x64 v10.3

Answer (score 3):

I feel really stupid.  I was trying sign the wrong .exe file.  Electron-forge creates two output directories when building an app, a directory called "make" and a directory with the name of your app.  I should have been signing the .exe in the make folder.  The .exe in the app name folder is a stand alone .exe that doesn't have any of the supported .dll files built into it.

Answer (score 0):

After run the

```
npx @electron-forge/cli import and `npm run make`
```

Inside the project folder path it creates **out** folder. Inside **out**, there are two folders make and electron..........
Go to make then 64x and then you can find .exe

Use that one. It will work without any issue.